# Is there a 64 bit deb for Crossover Impersonator?

Tags: installation, 11.04, 64-bit

Hi i just read about Crossover Linux [Crossover Impersonator](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/impersonator/) and wanted to try it out, however i read there is only a 32bit version. How can i run this on my 64 bit Ubuntu 11.04?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crossover Impersonator amd64.deb](http://media.codeweavers.com/pub/crossover/cxlinux/demo/ia32-crossover-standard-demo_10.0.0-1_amd64.deb) Well i found the 64bit version on their site. Thanks anyway